# Fraction ignored when integrating with u-substitution

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm learning u-substitution from Thomas' Calculus 14th edition and on page 295 I had the following example:

[image]

**My question is,** where is the $\frac{1}{8}$ at the end ? Shouldn't the answer be $-\frac{1}{8}cos(4x)+C$ ? Is this a mistake in the book ?

Comment: *You* are right.

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%281-2sin%5E2x%29sin%282x%29) agrees with you

Comment: Another typo in a textbook -- a little surprising to see something like that in a    **14th**  edition, but it may be a new addition to the text.  Proofreading of large textbooks is always imperfect (the answers section in a "mature" text typically has about a quarter to a third of a percent errors, somewhat higher in first or second editions).  This is simply something you have to be alert for, whether it's in  print  or in an on-line "book".